# Is there a way to instantly generate an array filled with a range of decreasing values in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, range

I know you can generate a normal range with `Array(0...10)`, but how about reversed?

For example:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `.reversed()` should do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
let tenToZero: [Int] = (0...10).reversed()
```

Note that it is necessary to specify the type here, otherwise it would use the overload of `reversed` that returns a `ReversedCollection`.

Alternatively, you can use either of the `stride` functions and use -1 for the `by` argument:

- [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641347-stride)
- [`stride(from:through:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641185-stride)

Example:

```
let tenToZero = Array(stride(from: 10, through: 0, by: -1))
```

Comment: or simply `Array((0...10).reversed())`

Comment: I do not like nested parentheses or overly-explicit typing. `(0...10).reversed() as Array`.